# CSS id attribute doesn't work with Safari web-browser

Tags: html, css, safari

I used the `<link>` tag in my HTML code and it links to my CSS code.
I made an ID attribute for one of my HTML tags and in the CSS I'm using `#idname { ... }`,
but when I open this in Safari, everything works fine except this ID...

In Windows everything works perfectly, even classes and IDs.
I have 2 textEdit files : html , stylesheet

Relevant HTML: In the `<head>` tag :

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
```

In the `<body>` tag :

```
<h2 id=“first”>about me</h2>
```

CSS

```
#first{
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #FF6600;
}
```

When I click on the html file, in Safari the "about me" color is black and it is not changed.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide the HTML and CSS necessary to reproduce your issue. Also, what do you mean by "not working"? What are you expecting to happen, and what is actually happening? I can almost guarantee you it isn't due to your text editor...

Comment: Could you please provide us some sort of a code from both HTML and CSS that you've used? And as nbrooks said, it's not your text editor that's causing the problems here, and Safari should not be a problem in this case either. How did you apply this ID Attribute in your HTML code?

Comment: Does your id starts with a number?

Comment: Is your quotation mark correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the wrong set of quotation marks:

```
<h2 id=“first”>about me</h2>
```

It should be:

```
<h2 id="first">about me</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But when I wanted to type " " they changed to “ ” What should I do?

Comment: I think then that it does have something to do with your editor. Try it in notepad/gedit/something that came with your system. See if this behaviour still occurs.

Also check your language input, make sure it's nothing something Asian, use English (U.S.)...see if that works?

Comment: As I said in notepad(windows) it works fine but in textEdit(mac) it changes the quotation marks. I also checked language input, it is U.S (english).

Comment: I see. This has already been asked on Ask Different. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120486/quotes-problem-in-mavericks-or-textedit. Let me know if that resolves your issue.